# Completely buffer command output before piping to another command?

Tags: shell, pipe, buffer

Is there a way to only execute a command after another is done without a temp file?
I have one longer running command and another command that formats the output and sends it to a HTTP server using curl.
If i just execute `commandA | commandB`, `commandB` will start `curl`, connect to the server and start sending data. Because `commandA`takes so long, the HTTP server will timeout.
I can do what I want with `commandA > /tmp/file && commandB </tmp/file && rm -f /tmp/file`

Out of curiosity I want to know if there is a way to do it without the temp file.
I tried `mbuffer -m 20M -q -P 100` but the curl process is still started right at the beginning. Mbuffer waits just until `commandA`is done with actually sending the data.
(The data itself is just a few hundred kb at max)

Comment: What about `commandA && commandB`?

Comment: that doesn't transmit the output of `commandA`to `commandB`, does it?

Comment: It starts Command B if Command A completes successfully, which would mean that curl doesn't start early.

Comment: @eyoung100 but it doesn't pass stdout from commandA to stdin for commandB, which is what Josef needs!

Comment: If he wants output passed, he has to use a file.  See cuonglm's answer.

Comment: Does your curl command possibly turn keepalives off with `--no-keepalive`?  Or possibly you could try shortening the keepalive period with `--keepalive-time 5` for example for a 5 second period.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is similar to a couple of the other answers. 
If you have the “moreutils” package, you should have the `sponge` command.  Try

```
commandA | sponge | { IFS= read -r x; { printf "%s\n" "$x"; cat; } | commandB; }
```

The `sponge` command is basically a pass-through filter (like `cat`)
except that it does not start writing the output until it has read the entire input. 
I.e., it “soaks up” the data, and then releases it when you squeeze it (like a sponge). 
So, to a certain extent, this is “cheating” –
if there’s a non-trivial amount of data, `sponge` almost certainly uses a temporary file. 
But it’s invisible to you; you don’t have to worry about housekeeping things
like choosing a unique filename and cleaning up afterwards.

The `{ IFS= read -r x; { printf "%s\n" "$x"; cat; } | commandB; }`
reads the first line of output from `sponge`. 
Remember, this doesn’t appear until `commandA` has finished. 
*Then* it fires up `commandB`, writes the first line to the pipe,
and invokes `cat` to read the rest of the output and write it to the pipe.

Comment: thanks! So `sponge` does that thing I used `mbuffer` for, but seems to be better suited here. using read is clever here. Definitely will remember this for the future.

Comment: @Josef: I've never heard of `mbuffer` before; it might actually be just as good as `sponge`. I agree that using `read` is a clever trick. I can't take full credit for it; it pops up in answers throughout Stack Exchange (U&L, Super User, Ask Ubuntu, etc.) from time to time. In fact, roaima's answer to this question is very similar to mine except it doesn't use `sponge` (or something equivalent), so, as I mentioned in a comment, it doesn't delay starting `commandB` as much as you need (in my understanding of your problem).

Comment: https://github.com/ildar-shaimordanov/perl-utils#sponge has a script version of "sponge" wrapped in a bash function.

Answer (score 7):

Commands in pipe line are started concurrently, you need to store `commandA` output somewhere to use later. You can avoid temp file by using variable:

```
output=$(command A; echo A)
printf '%s' "${output%%A}" | commandB
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the `echo A` in the process substitution?

Comment: @DigitalTrauma: It prevents command substitution from stripping trailing newlines.

Comment: Ah, I see, yes - good catch of a possible corner case

Comment: I realized my answer was incorrect, so I deleted it.  I think this looks correct instead. +1

Comment: Thanks a lot! Thats great and especially the echo A/%%A to keep the newline (even if I don't require that)

Comment: If the assumptions is to solve `commandA | commandB` with stdout of commandA completely buffered before going to stdin of commandB, then I cannot figure out where `A` comes from in this example. The `command` built-in is new to me, so maybe that is all. I do like this concept the best though for my purpose. `output="$(for x in $(_get-names); echo -n "$x"; _orderable-output "$(_work-with "$x")"; done;)"; echo -e "$output" | sort -k 2)` where anything prefixed with an underscore is a filler for a real process.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any standard UNIX utility that can address this issue. One option would be use `awk` to accumulate `commandA` output and flush it to `commandB` at one shot, like so

```
commandA  | awk '{x = x ORS $0}; END{printf "%s", x | "commandB"}'
```

Beware that this could be memory intensive since `awk` is building up a string from its input.

Comment: This strips off the last newline. Assuming that the last character _is_ a newline, you need a `\n` or another `ORS` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the requirement with a little script. This particular variant avoids the temporary file and potential memory hog at the expense of additional processes.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
IFS= read LINE

if test -n "$LINE"
then
    test -t 2 && echo "Starting $*" >&2
    (
        echo "$LINE"
        cat

    ) | "$@"
else
    exit 0
fi
```

If you were to call the script `waituntil` (and make it executable, put it in the `PATH`, etc), you'd use it like this

```
commandA... | waituntil commandB...
```

Example

```
( sleep 3 ; date ; id ) | waituntil nl
```

Comment: All this does is delay starting `commandB` until `commandA` has written _its first **line** of output_. That probably isn't good enough.

Comment: @G-Man but we don't know. I like your `sponge`. Off to read up on that one now.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option is [tac](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tac.1.html);

```
| tac | tac
```

Comment: This will still *start* `commandB` immediately; it will only delay sending it the data.