# Prevent the second command from starting in the bash pipe if the first command fails

Tags: bash, zsh, pipe

After learning (more or less) some useful discussions about pipes like
[Get exit status of process that's piped to another](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14270/get-exit-status-of-process-thats-piped-to-another) and [Exit when one process in pipe fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32684119/exit-when-one-process-in-pipe-fails) I still can't avoid starting the second command when the first command fails. Am I missing a fundamental detail about pipes?

So for example

```
$ somecommand | tar -T - -czf /tmp/someProject.tar.gz
```

shouldn't create the almost empty `tar.gz` file if `somecommand` didn't work properly and produced just a few error messages instead of the expected file list.

Comment: Are you open to workarounds that will still create the tarball but delete it immediately in the case where the command had failed? Something like `set -o pipefail; somecommand | tar -T - -czf /tmp/someProject.tar.gz || rm  /tmp/someProject.tar.gz`?

Comment: Possible approach: [`ifne`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/515915/108618).

Comment: So I shouldn't and won't look forward to the time. @terdon 's suggestion, however, is a nice solution. Thank you for all of your comments

Answer (score 28):

Yes, there is a bit of a fundamental detail about pipes there.

The point of a pipeline is to run the two or more commands in parallel, which avoids having to store all the data in full and can save time in that all processes can work at the same time. This by definition means that the second command starts before the first exits, so the exit status for the first isn't available yet.

The simple workaround is to use a temporary file instead. It shouldn't be much of a problem with storage here since we're passing just the list of file names, and not the data itself. E.g.:

```
tmp=$(mktemp)
if somecommand > "$tmp"; then
    tar -T - -czf /tmp/someProject.tar.gz < "$tmp"
fi
rm -f "$tmp"
```

---

Or indeed like terdon comments, just let the `tar` run, and remove the tar file afterwards if `somecommand` failed. But if `somecommand` produces a partial but significant list of files before failing, that can still cause some amount of unnecessary I/O when creating the to-be-removed archive.

Also, at least in GNU tar, by default `-T` does some processing of quotes and lines that look like command line options, so if you have nasty filenames, you may need to take that into account, or look into `--verbatim-files-from`, or `--null`. Similar issues might exist with other tar implementations.

Comment: Heh, I had just edited my answer to include that suggestion (albeit not as code example) ;)

Comment: @AdminBee, yepp, I was even going to write "the obvious workaround", you kinda proved that it is :P

Answer (score 12):

It seems as if you are misunderstanding the nature of piped commands.

In a pipeline of commands, *all* commands are started in parallel (see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/37508/377345) e.g.). That is why in your construct there is no way to have `tar` "wait" for successful completion of `somecommand`, because the `tar` reads the output that `somecommand` creates as it goes.

There are a few workarounds you could apply to alleviate the situation:

- buffer the output of `somecommand` in a temporary file and only run `tar` if the exit status of `somecommand` signals "success", and remove it afterwards (only feasible if you have sufficient storage space)
- as mentioned by @terdon, use the `pipefail` option to remove the unusable `tar.gz` file if `somecommand` had failed.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to use `&&`. Since you also want to capture the output, you can redirect it before and use it later.

```
somecommand > somefile && tar -T somefile -czf /tmp/someProject.tar.gz
```

If `somecommand` exits with anything other then `exit 0`, the `tar` will not be executed.

Answer (score -2):

While other answers are absolutely correct, a hackaround would look like

```
my-command | (sleep 1; tar cvf - output)
```

if my-command dies prematurely within 1 second, second pipe will get SIGPIPE and probably die too . You can obviously tune your buffer to nanosleep perl etc.

Comment: `SIGPIPE` is sent to the *writer*, not the reader, of a pipe. All you get in this example is an empty, or almost empty, `stdin`, no matter if you sleep a second or not.

Comment: apart from the `sleep` not helping, the command is messed up here. `tar f -` would also tell it to write the archive file to stdout, which here is connected to the terminal. That's usually not very useful, and at least GNU tar refuses to do it. Without `-T`, `tar` would look for filenames on the command line, so here, `output` would be taken as the name of a file to add to the archive.

Answer (score -4):

A pipe is not the way to do this. The `&&` construct executes the second command only when the first command succeeds.

E. g. in a directory where there is no file named "goober":

```
$ ls goober | echo "done"
done
ls: cannot access 'goober': No such file or directory
$ ls goober && echo "done"
ls: cannot access 'goober': No such file or directory
```

In your example:

```
$ somecommand && tar -T - -czf /tmp/someProject.tar.gz
```

if `somecommand` fails, then `tar` will not run.

Comment: In the question data flows from `somecommand` to `tar` and it's important it does. Your "solution" breaks this connection.

Comment: If `somecommand` succeeds, then `tar` will run as intended. The OP was complaining about `tar` running and creating an empty file because it had nothing to do when `somecommand` failed.

Comment: My point is the OP wants `tar` to read the output of `somecommand`. That's why [this other answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/657653/108618) uses a regular file. Your answer passes nothing to `tar` (it will read from the terminal or whatever the stdin of the shell is; it will not read from `somecommand`). For now it's more useless than the code from the question because your `tar` will *never* do what the OP wants.

Comment: Yes, he's going to have to change his tar command to specify what to tar -- which will be the output of somecommand.

Comment: ... only you will then need to store the output of `somecommand` somewhere, which brings us back to using a temporary file, as in the accepted answer.

Comment: Sure. And if `somecommand` is scp from another machine or wget from somewhere, that would be perfectly normal. But we don't know what `somecommand` does.  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Well, `tar -T -` means to get names of files to extract or add from stdin, so we can infer `somecommand` produces some list of filenames. With `... && tar -T - -czf foo.tar.gz`, the stdin of `tar` would still be connected to the terminal, and it would block waiting for the user to enter the file names. I guess you could then copypaste them from what `somecommand` printed, but that's not very user friendly, and it's actually exactly what pipes are for...